# When is it useful to compare floating-point values for equality?

Tags: algorithm, types, floating-point, integer

I seem to see people asking all the time around here questions about comparing floating-point numbers. The canonical answer is always: just see if the numbers are within some small number of each other…

So the question is this:  Why would you ever need to know if two floating point numbers are equal to each other?

In all my years of coding I have never needed to do this (although I will admit that even *I* am not omniscient).  From my point of view, if you are trying to use floating point numbers for and for some reason want to know if the numbers are equal, you should probably be using an integer type (or a decimal type in languages that support it).  Am I just missing something?

Comment: If you are going to downvote please explain why my question is worthy of downvoting

Comment: Different project requirements required different data types. Just because _you_ have never had to use it, doesn't mean there has never been a use-case that does.

Comment: @MattClark I realize that, which is why I am asking the question

Comment: @BilltheLizard The entire top page for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Floating+point+comparison) query....the people merely ask how they should compare floats, but do not explain why they need this.....

Comment: As soon as you do scientific, heavy maths or tight geometric work then you'll answer your question.

Comment: @Ripi2: StackOverflow is a site for collecting and preserving information. Can you state some examples instead of just saying somebody will find out? The latter does not seem helpful.

Comment: I have needed it when working on my synth. As soon as a signal (e.g. for an [ADSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#Attack_Decay_Sustain_Release_(ADSR)_envelope)) is below or above a certain level (e.g. during attack, decay or release), a new phase has to be intitiated.

Comment: In the synth again: when the (FP) phase accumulator is incremented (the increment is FP too) above a wavetable size, it must be wrapped around. The wavetable size is an integer, but not the current phase accumulator value.

Comment: And if you are plotting a graph, you generally try to remain inside the boundaries of the paper or bitmap or whatever. So you must compare again, and not just integer values.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Note that the question asks about comparing for exactly (=), not comparing generally (<, ≤, >, ≥).

Comment: I nominated to reopening the question. StackOverflow is a place for general programming knowledge, not just answers to bugs or specific technical details. Exploring what purposes specific floating-point operations serve is useful knowledge, especially for an operation that is contentious.

Comment: <Preparing a bag of popcorn> Let's see who wins: delete or reopen. <g>

Comment: What about, say, sorting or searching items in a list?

Comment: @Eric: While the question is interesting, it is IMO not a technical question about a specific programming problem, so not really a good match for Stack Overflow. I won't vote to delete, but I think it was right to put it on hold.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis On which site would it be a good question?

Comment: @curiousguy: I mostly read SO. I don't know which other site would be better. I just know that SO is not the one.

Answer (score 3):

A few reasons to compare floating-point numbers for equality are:

- Testing software. Given software that should conform to a precise specification, exact results might be known or feasibly computable, so a test program would compare the subject software’s results to the expected results.
- Performing exact arithmetic. Carefully designed software can perform exact arithmetic with floating-point. At its simplest, this may simply be integer arithmetic. (On platforms which provide IEEE-754 64-bit double-precision floating-point but only 32-bit integer arithmetic, floating-point arithmetic can be used to perform 53-bit integer arithmetic.) Comparing for equality when performing exact arithmetic is the same as comparing for equality with integer operations.
- Searching sorted or structured data. Floating-point values can be used as keys for searching, in which case testing for equality is necessary to determine that the sought item has been found. (There are issues if NaNs may be present, since they report false for any order test.)
- Avoiding poles and discontinuities. Functions may have special behaviors at certain points, the most obvious of which is division. Software may need to test for these points and divert execution to alternate methods.

Note that only the last of these tests for equality when using floating-point arithmetic to approximate real arithmetic. (This list of examples is not complete, so I do not expect this is the only such use.) The first three are special situations. Usually when using floating-point arithmetic, one is approximating real arithmetic and working with mostly continuous functions. Continuous functions are “okay” for working with floating-point arithmetic because they transmit errors in “normal” ways. For example, if your calculations so far have produced some *a*' that approximates an ideal mathematical result *a*, and you have a *b*' that approximates an ideal mathematical result *b*, then the computed sum *a*'+*b*' will approximate *a*+*b*.

Discontinuous functions, on the other hand, can disrupt this behavior. For example, if we attempt to round a number to the nearest integer, what happens when *a* is 3.49? Our approximation *a*' might be 3.48 or 3.51. When the rounding is computed, the approximation may produce 3 or 4, turning a very small error into a very large error. When working with discontinuous functions in floating-point arithmetic, one has to be careful. For example, consider evaluating the quadratic formula, (−*b*±sqrt(*b*<sup>2</sup>−4*ac*))/(2*a*). If there is a slight error during the calculations for *b*<sup>2</sup>−4*ac*, the result might be negative, and then `sqrt` will return NaN. So software cannot simply use floating-point arithmetic as if it easily approximated real arithmetic. The programmer must understand floating-point arithmetic and be wary of the pitfalls, and these issues and their solutions can be specific to the particular software and application.

Testing for equality is a discontinuous function. It is a function f(*a*, *b*) that is 0 everywhere except along the line *a*=*b*. Since it is a discontinuous function, it can turn small errors into large errors—it can report as equal numbers that are unequal if computed with ideal mathematics, and it can report as unequal numbers that are equal if computed with ideal mathematics.

With this view, we can see testing for equality is a member of a general class of functions. It is not any more special than square root or division—it is continuous in most places but discontinuous in some, and so its use must be treated with care. That care is customized to each application.

I will relate one place where testing for equality was very useful. We implement some math library routines that are specified to be faithfully rounded. The best quality for a routine is that it is correctly rounded. Consider a function whose exact mathematical result (for a particular input *x*) is *y*. In some cases, *y* is exactly representable in the floating-point format, in which case a good routine will return *y*. Often, *y* is not exactly representable. In this case, it is between two numbers representable in the floating-point format, some numbers *y*<sub>0</sub> and *y*<sub>1</sub>. If a routine is correctly rounded, it returns whichever of *y*<sub>0</sub> and *y*<sub>1</sub> is closer to *y*. (In case of a tie, it returns the one with an even low digit. Also, I am discussing only the round-to-nearest ties-to-even mode.)

If a routine is faithfully rounded, it is allowed to return either *y*<sub>0</sub> or *y*<sub>1</sub>.

Now, here is the problem we wanted to solve: We have some version of a single-precision routine, say `sin0`, that we know is faithfully rounded. We have a new version, `sin1`, and we want to test whether it is faithfully rounded. We have multiple-precision software that can evaluate the mathematical sin function to great precision, so we can use that to check whether the results of `sin1` are faithfully rounded. However, the multiple-precision software is slow, and we want to test all four billion inputs. `sin0` and `sin1` are both fast, but `sin1` is allowed to have outputs different from `sin0`, because `sin1` is only required to be faithfully rounded, not to be the same as `sin0`.

However, it happens that **most** of the `sin1` results are the same as `sin0`. (This is partly a result of how math library routines are designed, using some extra precision to get a very close result before using a few final arithmetic operations to deliver the final result. That tends to get the correctly rounded result **most** of the time but **sometimes** slips to the next nearest value.) So what we can do is this:

- For each input, calculate both `sin0` and `sin1`.
- Compare the results for equality.
- If the results are equal, we are done. If they are not, use the extended precision software to test whether the `sin1` result is faithfully rounded.

Again, this is a special case for using floating-point arithmetic. But it is one where testing for equality serves very well; the final test program runs in a few minutes instead of many hours.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I needed, it was to check if the GPU was IEEE 754 compliant.
It was not.

Anyway I haven't used a comparison with a programming language. I just run the program on the CPU and on the GPU producing some binary output (no literals) and compared the outputs with a simple diff.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty possible reasons.

Since I know Squeak/Pharo Smalltalk better, here are a few trivial examples taken out of it (it relies on strict IEEE 754 model):

```
Float>>isFinite
    "simple, byte-order independent test for rejecting Not-a-Number and (Negative)Infinity"

    ^(self - self) = 0.0

Float>>isInfinite
    "Return true if the receiver is positive or negative infinity."

    ^ self = Infinity or: [self = NegativeInfinity]

Float>>predecessor
    | ulp |
    self isFinite ifFalse: [
        (self isNaN or: [self negative]) ifTrue: [^self].
        ^Float fmax].
    ulp := self ulp.
    ^self - (0.5 * ulp) = self
        ifTrue: [self - ulp]
        ifFalse: [self - (0.5 * ulp)]
```

I'm sure that you would find some more involved `==` if you open some libm implementation and check... Unfortunately, I don't know how to search == thru github web interface, but manually I found this example in julia libm (a variant of fdlibm)
https://github.com/JuliaLang/openlibm/blob/master/src/s_remquo.c

```
remquo(double x, double y, int *quo)
{
...
fixup:
    INSERT_WORDS(x,hx,lx);
    y = fabs(y);
    if (y < 0x1p-1021) {
        if (x+x>y || (x+x==y && (q & 1))) {
        q++;
        x-=y;
        }
    } else if (x>0.5*y || (x==0.5*y && (q & 1))) {
        q++;
        x-=y;
    }
    GET_HIGH_WORD(hx,x);
    SET_HIGH_WORD(x,hx^sx);
    q &= 0x7fffffff;
    *quo = (sxy ? -q : q);
    return x;
```

Here, the remainder function answer a result `x` between -y/2 and y/2. If it is exactly y/2, then there are 2 choices (a tie)... The == test in fixup is here to test the case of **exact** tie (resolved so as to always have an even quotient).

There are also a few `==zero` tests, for example in __ieee754_logf (test for trivial case log(1)) or __ieee754_rem_pio2 (modulo pi/2 used for trigonometric functions).