# How to handle (set conditions and compare) signed floats in C?

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm trying to compare 2 float variables.

But comparison failed because of different sign:

```
int main()
{
    //---------------------------------
    float d = 0.1;
    float f1, f2;
    printf("data: %.1f\n", d);
    //---------------------------------
    d -= 0.1; // 0.0
    f1 = d;
    printf("data: %.1f\n", d);
    printf("f1: %.1f\n", f1);
    //---------------------------------
    d -= 0.1; // -0.1
    printf("data: %.1f\n", d);
    //--------------------------------
    d += 0.1; // -0.0
    f2 = d;
    printf("data: %.1f\n", d);
    printf("f2: %.1f\n", f2);
    //---------------------------------

    if (f1 == f2)
    {
        printf("f1 and f2 equals\n");  // should get here
    }
    else
    {
        printf("f1 and f2 NOT equals\n");
    }

    if (f2 != -0.0)
    {
        printf("f2 NOT equal -0.0 \n"); // should get here
    }
    else
    {
        printf("f2 equals -0.0 \n"); 
    }
}
```

Output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJxYV.png)

- data: 0.1
- data: 0.0
- f1: 0.0
- data: -0.1
- data: -0.0
- f2: -0.0
- f1 and f2 NOT equals
- f2 NOT equal -0.0

How can I properly set conditions to compare -0.0 and 0.0 values?

Comment: Don't seem duplicate but related: [language agnostic - Is floating point math broken? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Try adding a lot more decimal places to the outputs.

Comment: Try changing all the floating point constants (which the compiler parses as doubles and then converts to  floats) to genune float constants (eg replace 0.1 with 0.1f).

Comment: Note that `0.1` cannot be exactly represented by binary floating point. Unlike in decimal, it is a recurring fraction.

Comment: When doing floating point operations, due to the imperfect precision of using a finite number of binary digits to represent numbers that require more digits (finite or infinite), you cannot compare direct equality. You have to allow for some "tolerance" (*e.g.*, differing by less than some very small fraction). @Pedro provides a bit more detail in this regard.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The question incorrectly asks about −0 and +0, but at least one of the actual numbers is not a zero. It is a small non-zero number that is merely shown with “0.0” due to limited output precision. Actual −0 and +0 compare as equal.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually a limitation of accuracy that makes it difficult for you here, every calculation is made with limited accuracy

[long explanation at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)

To overcome this you would need to allow certain ranges:

```
if (f1 == f2)
```

could become

```
if( ((f1 - f2) < 0.001) &&  ((f1 - f2) > -0.001) )
```

when you can tolerate the given range of 0.001, otherwise choose according to your need.
Same for

```
if (f2 != -0.0)
```

you should specify a range here too, because with some calculations you only occasionally hit a given constant value. Hope this helps.

Comment: Or a little more concisely, `if ( fabs(f1 - f2) < 0.001 )...` :)

Comment: thats better I guess, one might check which is actually faster if that matters, but I guess yours is best

Comment: [Allowing “tolerance” in floating-point comparison is often not the right solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685306/298225)

Comment: @Pedro I agree it may not be faster. It was just a mild suggestion since I think it's a little bit clearer. Mathematically, that's how one would normally express that inequality.

Comment: @Pedro: the fabs() version is more readable, i.e. it makes reading the code easier, and that is an important property of good source code. Speed is probably not much of an issue here.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: No, not just as often. Certainly on Stack Overflow, the overwhelming majority of questions involving floating-point comparison are situations where a person incorrectly expected equality where it is not warranted, and using comparison with a tolerance will not solve the actual problem, at least not reliably.

Comment: @Eric: IME, just as often. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Would you provide some examples I could add to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685306/298225)?

Answer (score 0):

In C, `0.1` is a double precision floating point constant i.e. it can be thought of as having type `double`. 0.1 cannot be represented exactly by either a `float` or a `double`. It's a bit like 1/3 is not representable exactly in base 10 with a finite number of digits.

The conversions needed to add `0.1` to a `float` lose precision (it chops off some of the fraction digits) which makes it hard to do equality comparisons.

You have three options. You're program will work as you expect if you either

- replace the `float` declarations with `double` declarations
- replace every instance of `0.1` with `0.1f`
- use Pedro's suggestion

The former makes your variables double precision numbers and the later makes your constants single precision numbers.

There is, however, a wider issue with comparing floating point values for equality in that, except for fractions where the denominator is a power of 2, no number is expressible exactly as a `float` or a `double`. You need to be doing something like [what Pedro suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54944684/169346).

Comment: Using homogeneous types would resolve the discrepancies in this particular code but not in general.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know. That's why the last paragraph.